# Conceptual understanding of convergence of improper integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Statement**

If $f$ is monotonic decreasing for all $x\leq1$ and $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$, then the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ and the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}f(n)$ both converge or diverge together.

This can be proved easily (proof similar to the proof of integral test).

**Doubts**

> 1. Give an example of nonmonotonic $f$ for which $\sum_{1}^{\infty}f(n)$ converges but $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ diverges.
> 2. If $f$ is monotonic, and if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n}f(x)\,dx$ exists, then the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ converges. How to prove this?
> 3. In the previous statements, is monotonicity necessary? What if $f$ is *nonmonotonic* but $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n}f(x)\,dx$ exists?
> 4. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n}f(x)\,dx=A$, then $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ converges to $A$. How to prove this?
> 5. If the sequence $\left\{\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n}f(x)\,dx\right\}$ converges, then $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ converges. True or false and why?
> 6. If $f$ is positive and if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n}f(x)\,dx=A$, then  $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ converges to A. True or false and why?
> 7. If $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ converges, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n}f(x)\,dx =0$.
> 8. Suppose $|f'(x)|<M$ for all $x>0$. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n}f(x)\,dx=A$,then $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ converges to $A$. Why?

Comment: $f(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$ is an example where the series converges, but the integral does not.

Comment: " monotonic decreasing for all $x\leq1$ "?

Comment: This is way too many questions posed as one question.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, think of a function where $f(n)=0$ for all $n$.

The second part looks to be incorrectly stated, as the $x$ inside the integral is a dummy variable that I would not expect to be in the limit.

If I switch the $x$ to an $n$ in the limit, it's not true. Consider $f(x)=1$.

Essentially, we need to know which conditions apply to $f$ for part 2.